# How to get the initial value of a component property?

Tags: delphi, components

Let's take an example of a component that contain a property called `ColumnWidth` with the default value 50. During design-time I change the value to 100 and then I compile the application.

Now, I would like to implement a `Reset to default` (popup menu) button inside of my component, that will initialize the `ColumnWidth` to value 100, in case the user change it meanwhile.

```
TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FVirtualStringTree: TVirtualStringTree;
    FColumnWidth: Integer;
    FColumnWidthDef: Integer;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure ResetToDefault;
  published
    property ColumnWidth: Integer read FColumnWidth write SetColumnWidth  default 50;
    property VirtualStringTree: TVirtualStringTree read FVirtualStringTree  write FVirtualStringTree; 
  end;

constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FColumnWidth:= 50;
end;

destructor TMyComponent.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.SetColumnWidth(const Value: Integer);
begin
  if FColumnWidth <> Value then FColumnWidth:= Value;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.ResetToDefault;
begin
  ColumnWidth:= FColumnWidthDef;
end;
```

Under the component methods, how can I store the initial value of `ColumnWidth`?

Comment: Why don't you use a constant everywhere?

Comment: Didn't the answer you got to the same question a couple of weeks ago, with the addition of @RobKennedy s comment work as you wanted?

Comment: For the previous "similar" question I had in mind the same think to do, but with a mistake from me. I thought I need to do it from design-time, but in fact it's necessary to do it during real-time. Now I think this question is more clear. Programming is a hobby and not a job, so internet and Stackoverflow are my only trainers. Thank you for your understanding if sometimes I put silly questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value 100 is not available inside the component as it is stored in the DFM resource of the form, frame or datamodule where the component resides. Alas, it might get tedious to read that value later from the DFM again (although possible). Therefore you better save the value in a form field during the `FormCreate` event and use this later to reset that component property to the saved value.

Comment: I believe `FColumnWidthDef` is there for that purpose.